# Foregrounding selected node and edge in cytoscapejs

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a really huge network. In my webapp, I want to be able to select nodes and edges then I change the style to selected stylesheet. I have succeed with this but the problem is the edges always behind another nodes because it is too crowded. Is it possible to make all  selected nodes and edges to be in the foreground? I knwo about z-index but it seems it can not set selected nodes and edges to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

See the visibility style properties: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/visibility

From the docs:

> - **`z-compound-depth`** : May be `bottom`, `orphan`, `auto` (default), or `top`.  The first drawn is `bottom`, the second is `orphan`, which is the same depth as the root of the compound graph, followed by the default of `auto` which draws in depth order from root to leaves of the compound graph.  The last drawn is `top`.
> - **`z-index-compare`**: May be `auto` (default) or `manual`.  The `auto` setting draws edges under nodes, whereas `manual` ignores this convention and draws solely based on the `z-index` value.
> - **`z-index`** : An integer value that affects the relative draw order of elements.  In general, an element with a higher `z-index` will be drawn on top of an element with a lower `z-index` within the same depth.

So, you need to set at least `z-index-compare: manual` and `z-index` if you generally want edges over nodes.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.